# Send Email button is not showing in activity history for community in salesforce

Tags: community, sandbox, send-email

I have added the related list of Activity History under case object & also added the send email button on activity history but it is not showing under case related list in community and even though it has all access.

How to show the send email button on activity history in community ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the community page where you can't see the button?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to edit page layouts, open a case record and click 'Edit Layout'

Then go down to the bottom to see the related lists and click the wrench on the 'Activity History' related list.

Click the '+' on buttons and check the box for 'Send an Email', then click 'OK' and 'Save' the changes to the page layout.

You will be able to see the button on Community if it is enabled from your org

Answer (score 0):

This button / action visibility within a Lightning Community is controlled via the Global Publisher layout. If the Email action is not present on the layout then it will not display on the Activity History related list. You can confirm this by going doing the following:

1. Go to Setup > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts > Global Layout.
2. Edit the Global Layout.
3. Locate the Email Mobile & Lightning Action called "Email".
4. Add this to the Layout.
5. Save

Clear your browser cache and log back into the Community and access a record where the Send Email action was not present, it should now be restored.